# Save a document library template with pages that has web parts and then create a new library in SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint

I have a document library with a few pages and each page has some web parts that displays data from different views.

If I create a back up of the whole site and restore it somewhere else I still have the pages with the web parts in the new site.

But if I create a document library template (with content) and then create a new document library using that template in the same site all the pages are empty (no web parts). How should I solve this, to be able to keep the web parts in the new library?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Probably one solution is to use site template if you are migrating pages. Its not all web parts get erased when you create a library from template your list view, third party web parts not activated on your new site are the ones which could go missing. but if you are using RSS viewer and similar OOTB provided web parts they will remain on your pages